# Is Object Relational Mapper the holy Grail?

Tags: orm

They seem complex and unnecessary. The applications I've built at work or home have never used any ORM and many of them haven't been even Object-oriented. Is it depenpable about size when they can be useful. How to determine how big a application should be when they be useful?

Comment: Any answers to this will be subjective and so this really should be marked as a community wiki question.

Comment: There are already questions on this topic. Please search.

Comment: Is software development objective? Think not, it's highly subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Silver Bullet. I am sure you must have heard it a lot of times. But its true. ORM is useful due to [Object-Relational Impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).
ORM allow you to think or program database in YOUR programming language.

Comment: Yeah that's the best part of it. Everything is just plain objects. No more sql strings..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an O/RM, but neither do you need a high level programming language such as C# or C++, you could just write your application using assembly. Those were the good old days ;-)

Answer (score 1):

ORMs do have distinct advantages over running straight-up SQL queries:

- Save/update/delete an entire object graph
- Versioning of entities to check for stale state
- Better code maintenance and compile-time checking (SQL queries are magic strings)
- Can generate database schema from object model

However, they do have some disadvantages:

- Requires a sizable amount of time to set up
- Mappings must be kept up to date
- Even though it maps tables to objects, you still need to know SQL
- Slower than straight-up SQL (but only apparent when doing bulk operations)

Overall, the benefits of learning and using an ORM far outweigh its disadvantages, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Padmarag says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324477/is-object-relational-mapper-the-holy-grail/2324513#2324513), ORMs aren't a silver bullet.

If you have a hugely complex (object-oriented) domain model you might be better off using an [Object database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database).

Answer (score 0):

ORM-Mapper are nowadays the way to communicate with RDBMS. But you don't need in every application an RDBMS. There are several NoSQL-Solutions, which are maybe more appropriate to use.

But there are use-cases where I don't prefer an ORM: Reporting an batch processing: Here it's a question about performance an also a question of the complexity of queries. In a such scenario there is maybe the use of stored procedures more appropriate.